# Firebase not validating email

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, email-verification

I'm currently creating an app using Flutter.

The goal is to check to see if an account's email is verified before logging them in.

As it is now, a user signs in to their account using `Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword`

At this point, `Auth.isEmailVerified` returns false

Afterwards, a verification email is sent, the user then clicks on the link to verify their account and a window popup appears stating that their account is now verified.

The user tries to login again, but `Auth.isEmailVerified` still returns false.

Any ideas?

This is the `auth.dart` class file I'm using.

https://github.com/AndriousSolutions/auth/blob/master/lib/auth.dart

And this is my code.

```
   child: MaterialButton(
      minWidth: 200.0,
      height: 42.0,
      onPressed: () async {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: emailAddressController.text,
                  password: passwordController.text)
              .then((onSuccess) {
            Auth.reload();
            if ((onSuccess)) {
              if (Auth.isEmailVerified) {
                db.createUser(
                    emailAddress: Auth.email,
                    firstName: Tools.getFirstName(Auth.displayName),
                    googleAccount: false);
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomePage.tag);
              } else {
                emailVerificationDialog(context);
                Auth.sendEmailVerification();
              }
            }
          }).catchError((e) {
            print(" LSAHJDSAKHDSA " + e);
          });
        }
      },
      color: ThemeSettings.RaisedButtonColor,
      child: Text('Log In', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    ),
```

Thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the library that you are using the `Auth.reload` call needs to be awaited. It should be

```
    static Future<bool> reload() async {
      await _user?.reload();
      return _setUserFromFireBase(_user);
    }
```

Since it is not awaiting on reload, the your code simply keeps on going and it checks `isEmailVerified` before it has a chance to complete the reload.

This [issue](https://github.com/AndriousSolutions/auth/issues/1) is reporting it which I have shared this info.